# Magento2 | How to call Template from a Controller

Tags: magento2, template, controllers

I got this controller:

```
<?php    
class MyClass extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order
{
    public function execute()
    {     
        echo "TEST";
    }
}
?>
```

I want it to call a template. How can I do that?

Comment: create handler on layout file and call phtml.

Comment: From a front-end dev - Please do not do it this way, calling a template from a PHP files makes life much more difficult if a FE dev ever wants to debug or make changes via layout XML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**check the below code**

```
 /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context     $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory

    ) {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__(' heading '));

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Companyname\Module\Block\blockname')
                ->setTemplate('Companyname_Module::test.phtml')
                ->toHtml();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In controller:**

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use OX\OfferNotifier\Helper\Data;

class Index extends Action
{

    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $_resultJsonFactory;
    protected $_helperData;

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory, JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory, Data $data)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->_helperData = $data;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->_helperData->isOfferNotifierEnabled()) {
            $result = $this->_resultJsonFactory->create();
            $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
            $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam("productId");
            $offerInProductView = $this->getRequest()->getParam("offerInProductView") ?? 0;
            $url = $this->getRequest()->getParam("url") ?? 0;
            //Get the product id for ProductView Page 
            if ($offerInProductView) {
                $productInfo = $resultPage->getLayout()
                        ->createBlock('OOO\YYY\Block\Product\View')
                        ->setData('product_id', $productId)
                        ->setData('offer_in_product_view', $offerInProductView)
                        ->setTemplate('OOO_YYY::product/view/offer-notifier.phtml')
                        ->toHtml();
            }


            $result->setData(['content' => $productInfo]);
            return $result;
        }
    }

}
```